# Proper way to do Guice singleton service injection into Quartz tasks, Stripes ActionBeans and ServletContextListeners?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

At the moment I'm using a static singleton to obtain the singleton service that Guice 3.0 builds for me through DI - I believe this a terrible hack and not at all the intended way to use Guice for DI, and complicates unit testing.

```
public class ServiceProvider {
    private static ServiceProvider instance = new ServiceProvider();    
    private MyService myService;

    public ServiceProvider() {      
        Injector myInjector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
        myService = noobmeterInjector.getInstance(MyService.class);
    }

    public static MyService getMyService() {
        return instance.myService;
    }
}
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to fix that, as I need that service in at least four different spots:

- Stripes ActionBeans - I think the [Stripes Guice plugin](http://bgoodin.github.io/stripes-guice/) would help me there, and I did connect it but ended up with multiple parallel MyServices
- ServletContextListener - I think possibly the [Guice Servlet module](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule) can help somehow, although I'm struggling with the documentation as it mostly discusses replacing web.xml with Guice configuration (not my priority at this point) and injecting HttpServletRequests into Guice-constructed objects (again not what I want to do)
- Quartz Jobs - here I found [something relevant](http://www.codesmell.org/blog/2009/01/quartz-fits/), but not sure if it won't end up still creating a "parallel" MyService to the other ones
- Batch processes run from command line - this is the easy part

The MyService service is intended to be a singleton (other services it owns open DB/MQ connections, etc., so creating multiple of these would be bad).

Is there some simple way how to do this in Guice that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few issues with your code snippet.

- You should no longer be implementing singletons as static variables; let Guice do the lifecycle management for you.
- In this example, `ServiceProvider` is basically a Service Locator implementation, which is unnecessary since you're using Guice.
- It's good practice to keep the `Injector` creation as "high" up as possible. The `main` method where your server starts would be a good place.

I've added some code to  demonstrate.

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
        // Your code here.
    }
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
         // Assuming MyService implements Service
         bind(Service.class).to(MyService.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: My application is a web application (Stripes under Java Servlets), so doesn't really have a 'main' method. How should I approach that?

Comment: Look into [stripes-guice](http://bgoodin.github.io/stripes-guice/). You can extend `GuiceContextListener` to configure and instantiate your `Injector`, and stripes-guice will take care of injecting `ActionBean`s for you.

Comment: I need the same singleton service injected in both Stripes ActionBeans and Quartz Jobs (which the GuiceContextListener won't really apply to).

Comment: Where are you instantiating your `Scheduler`?

Comment: From Guice module I build own scheduler service class `bind(SchedulerService.class).to(SchedulerServiceImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();` which instantiates `StdSchedulerFactory`. But the Quartz jobs themselves (implementations of `org.quartz.Job`) are instantiated by Quartz itself AFAIK.